# "gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device" on MacOS with Maven

Tags: macos, maven, homebrew, gnupg

I have installed GPG via Homebrew with `brew install gpg`.
It is installed in version `2.2.17`.

In my Maven POM I have this snippet:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>sign-artifacts</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>sign</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

However when running `mvn clean verify` I get this error:

```
gpg: Beglaubigung fehlgeschlagen: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: signing failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Try running maven with the `-X` argument to find the gpg command line that's actually executed.

Comment: @JimmyB Unfortunately there ain't any gpg commands print when using `-X`.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

I have added

```bash
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

to my `~/.bash_profile` file. Now it is working.

See also https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/14737#issuecomment-309848851

Comment: This fix worked on my linux machine too. I had gotten the error when piping gpg into ssh.

Comment: or `export GPG_TTY=$(tty)`

Comment: @Amerousful the given two-line solution is preferred because it doesn't hide the exit code. (Try `export test=$(exit 1); echo $?`)

Comment: Also worked on Ubuntu running in WSL

Answer (score 50):

On macOS you may want to use `pinentry-mac` to have GUI window to enter pin and optionally store pin in keychain.

You can install it though Homebrew:

```
brew install pinentry-mac
```

And enable it with the following line in your `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` config (create it if it doesn't exists):

```
pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac
```

Comment: It works once `killall gpg-agent` has been ran after applying your proposal.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is probably the better way, not sure why this doesn't have more upvotes.

Comment: For me the path was `pinentry-program /opt/homebrew/bin/pinentry-mac`

Comment: Here's a complete answer from [GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/managing-commit-signature-verification/telling-git-about-your-signing-key#telling-git-about-your-gpg-key).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```bash
gpg --use-agent --armor --detach-sign --output $(mktemp) pom.xml
```

Comment: GPG stopped working for me randomly. This worked like a charm and I still have no idea why.  Its like the agent had to be kicked or something.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this happened because the terminal window wasn't big enough to fit the passphrase TUI. Once I opened a bigger terminal tab and then I rerun the gpg command, I was able to see the passphrase terminal user interface.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody gets this error message when typing `gpg` commands in bash, try adding `--no-tty`. That fixed it for me.

Comment: This doesn't work, getting this error again and again. I seriously start to feel nobody knows and just toss random solutions around. What to do then?

Comment: @EricBuist. A lot of IT is like that. You google for ideas and try stuff until something works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was happening because pinentry was try to use brew version of gpu instead of the bundled version of the gpg MacOS app.
It can be seen after running `gpgconf`
I resolved this issue by uninstalling the brew versions of gpg and gnupg