# "gpg: signing failed: inappropriate ioctl for device" publish scala library to maven central

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, gnupg, sonatype

This is my first time publishing Scala library into maven central. I follow [this tutorial from Scala docs](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Using-Sonatype.html). After I prepare everything, I want to publish my library in SBT shell with command `publishSigned`, then I get the error about "gpg: signing failed: inappropriate ioctl for device". I did google and try to find the solutions, Here is some sources I find from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57591432/gpg-signing-failed-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-on-macos-with-maven) and [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#Invalid_IPC_response_and_Inappropriate_ioctl_for_device). I try to add `$ export GPG_TTY=$(tty)` into my `~/.bash_profile` , but It does not work for me. It looks like sbt shell does not able to get `gpg` credentials in anyway.

How do I fix it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to sign something with `gpg` from command line to check that it's working (without Scala, sbt, sbt pugins). I had different error `gpg: signing failed: No secret key`. My gpg was old and I couldn't update it. My credentials were 2 years old and although they were set up not to expire gpg wanted me to enter `passphrase`. I downloaded GnuPG Desktop from https://gnupg.org/download/index.html , run it and enter my passphrase in pop-up window after I enter `publishSigned`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by downloading GPG Suite, and then typing passphrase manually